# Not able to render the request to another html from controller using angularjs + spring MVC 3.0

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, controller, angularjs, modelandview

Logon.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="angularspring">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller="LogonController">

    <form>
            <div>
                TextBox : <input type="text"  ng-model="person.userName" />
            </div>
            <div>
                Password : <input type="password" ng-model="person.passWord" />
            </div>
            <div ng-view></div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="login(person)"> Submit 

            </button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.i18n.properties-min-1.0.9.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/base64.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </body>


    </html>
```

controller.js

```
        var as = angular.module('angularspring',[]);


        as.controller('LogonController', function ($scope, $http) {
            var actionUrl = 'action/checkUserNameAndPassword/';


             $scope.login = function (person) {

                 $http.post(actionUrl,$scope.person);
             };


        });
```

web.xml

```
    <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/action-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/action/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


        <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>logon.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
```

In action-servlet.xml file contains the below tags and classes

action-servlet.xml

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>    

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pack" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"></bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
      <property name="prefix" value="" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".html" />

    </bean>
```

LogonController.java

In LogonController i am able to get the request values that are bind to person object but i am not able to render the request to logonSuccess.html

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkUserNameAndPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody 
    public ModelAndView logon(@RequestBody Person person) {

            return new ModelAndView("WEB-INF/views/logonSuccess");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are able to bind the modelattribute but not able to dispatch to the required view.

Here's what i observe

You have the `@ResponseBody` annotation on your `logon` method but it returns a `ModelandView` object.

If you want to return to a html view then remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

You can read more about this [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

Also in the `action-servlet.xml` specify the `prefix` property of the `viewResolver` with the location of your html files which i think is `WEB-INF/views`

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.html</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now you can return the `ModelandView` like

```
 return new ModelAndView("logonSuccess");
```

Comment: I tried it as you said I removed the @ResponseBody and i modified the changes in the action-servlet.xml file . But i am facing the same problem .

Comment: I am using angularJs with Spring MVC.                                   No error is displaying.

Comment: Do you want to direct to logonSucess.html? what does this html contain? Are you able to check if the request reaches the controller atleast?

Comment: Sorry for the later reply.logonSuccess.html file contains only success message.yes i am able to see the request reaching the controller  . But i am not able to redirect to logonSuccess.html.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. From the login page, I was trying to redirect to the home page on successful login. I was using angular js and spring mvc rest controllers. I was doing a http.post from angularjs and my rest controlelr was doing the authentication and returning a model and view object. But then angularjs was not redirecting me to the home page.

Then i changed my angularjs implementation and it worked. Try doing a form submit from angularjs to the controller and not a http.post or http.get. Now the page is redirected to the home page or the error page, whatever view being set in the ModelAndView object in the REST controller.